# Force Music to play in browsers

Tags: javascript, html, audio, browser

At this website: emuspin.com    the creator causes an audio file to be played automatically upon the page loading.  I've tried using the audio html tag to do this but the user is almost always prompted if they want to download the file or allow it to play and after much searching I can't find the author's source code that forces this audio to play automatically. Does anyone have any idea what he may have used to force an audio file to play automatically in the user's browser?

Edit: just to specify, I am making a bookmarklet, which is why I need to file to play without the user having to click an "accept" button or something like that, this program does stuff to the web page that you are currently on when you click it.

Comment: Um, the Web site's source code is [publically available](https://github.com/feross/EmuSpin.com). Look at the "built with" to see how it's done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<audio autoplay src="http://www.quackit.com/music/good_enough.mp3">
<p>If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the audio element.</p>
</audio>​
```

obviously edit the src attribute to your liking

I would also like to note that autoplay annoys users and may keep from generating traffic.

Comment: "autoplay annoys users and may keep from generating traffic" Completely agree. Esp when you open multiple tabs, you don't know, which tab is playing music!!